# ResolvePrincipal vs SearchPrincipal

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So I'm attempting to write something to mimic sharepoint's people picker. I was originally using `Utility.ResolvePrincipal` with some success, but it was only returning me a single user (obviously). So, I tried to use `Utility.SearchPrincipal`. Only that's not returning me anything. Here's what I have:

```
var user = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(_clientContext, _clientContext.Web, nameStart, PrincipalType.user, PrincipalSource.All, null, false);
var users = Utility.SearchPrincipals(_clientContext, _clientContext.Web, nameStart, PrincipalType.user, PrincipalSource.All, null, 10);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

At this point, user.Value has a single user, and users is an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue by changing the `PrincipalSource.All` call in `Utility.SearchPrincipals` to just `PrincipalSource.UserInfoList`. Apparently it was running into some security issue in one of the sets of users, and instead of throwing an error it was just returning an empty list.